# Alternative ways to add rotation to an object?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, rigid-body-simulation, empty

I baked a rigid body simulation of a ball falling down the stairs. The ball's trajectory is ok, but I want to add additional rotation to the ball. The simulation is baked to keyframes. It would be very cumbersome to manipulate each individual keyframe for further rotation.
I thought about parenting an empty to the ball and then rotating the empty. The problem is: the ball needs to be the parent to make the empty follow the ball. But the empty needs to be the parent to make the ball rotate. Actually, both need to be parents. Or is there a modifier or node-based solution to make the ball rotate more?

Comment: you could duplicate your object, now you have object A and B, object A is the one that has the baked simulation, remove this animation from B. Parent B to A, make A invisible, keyframe the rotation you want for B, B will rotate and follow A's animation

Comment: Why does the ball need to have additional rotation?

Comment: @moonboots man, that's pretty damn genius...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could duplicate your object, now you have object A and B, object A is the one that has the baked simulation, remove this animation from B. Parent B to A, make A invisible, keyframe the rotation you want for B, B will both rotate and follow A's animation.

Answer (score 3):

One way to "fake" rotation because you already have baked everything would be to manipulate the shader like this:

[image]

if you use this node setup, you can rotate your shader as you want:

[image]

But honestly, i think it would be easier to give the ball initial speed and rotation by setting keyframes and then uncheck "animated" and set keyframe in rigid body settings so that it is physically correct and let Blender do the work.

Comment: does it only work for pink balls?

Comment: Unfortunately…yes. This is another restriction of Blender i don‘t understand. Well…maybe in Blender 476.31451 the developer will improve this. ‼️

Comment: you two are hilarious ... 